# Using linux script command

Tags: linux, bash, shell

The `script` command executes and records logs.

( http://www.computerhope.com/unix/uscript.htm )

( http://linuxers.org/article/script-command-line-tool-recordsave-your-terminal-activity )

I use `script` command for saving commands and those output.

Whenever using 'script', I type commands like followings.

```
$ script result.log
Script started, file is result.log
$ date
$ ls -la.
$ exit
```

Sometimes I want to use those command with shell script.

So I run like following.

```
$ script -c test.sh result.log
```

But the result.log has only output, it doesn't contain command itself.
I want the result.log to include commands and output.

How can I do it?

Thanks

Comment: All these years I didn't know about this command. Nice one, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

if you use sh -x to run your script it will print the commands or add
set -x to your script.

```
script -c "sh -x ./test.sh" reult.log
```

sample output:

```
+ date
Tue Dec 23 09:52:22 CET 2014
+ ls -la
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 set -o verbose
```

Execute this on terminal before executing your script or add this at the beginning of the script.

This will change the terminal configuration to echo all the commands before executing them.

This will add the command then followed by the output of that command.

you can also use :

```
 set -x or set -v set -xv
```

**-x** option enables variable expansion and echo's all the option used with the command.

**-v** is similar to **-o verbose** this simply echo's the command name

**-xv** echo's both.